# OBD-II Enhanced PIDs

Tags: ford, transmission, obd-ii, hyundai, torque

I was looking at the Torque Pro app and in the section where there is a list of custom PIDs that can be used, one is a Transmission Temperature PID. But it is exactly same as Engine Coolant Temperature PID (Mode 01 PID 05). How can both be the same?
Is there any source where these custom PIDs have been listed? Torque Pro app lists some like Ford, Toyota Prius, but not all.
I have a Hyundai i10 Era 2010, and would like to start using custom PIDs from Hyundai.

Comment: When you say they are exactly the same, do you mean that the Mode and PID are identical? Or the values you see are the same? In terms of the car, they can't be the same all the time. So I'm wondering if it's a reporting problem, or is it the same for your car because it's not actually defined. For a 2010 I would think there is a sensor for that, but not 100% sure for that car.

Comment: Mode, PID are identical and the values are the same too, which is not possible. Also there are 3 methods - Transmission Temperature PID(Method1,2,3) which I have no clue what they are.

Comment: I so need to learn how data is transfered on OBD-II and how it gets there from CAN. I need it for work to, so good thing to know. Isn't the way data is identified is by mode and PID? Which means if they are the same, then the value returned is not a copy or something that's close, it's the same data. The fact that the name changes the fetched data is the same data, not a copy. E.G. if you name the front door on your house A, and also give it the name B, then regardless of whether you say A or B you mean the same physical thing. Same for this.